# spring cloud and spring boot compatibility issue in pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to run my application

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Please find below pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I hope this issue was related to spring cloud and spring boot version compatibility issue. Can someone please help me to resolve it?

Comment: Letting maven handle dependency management is the right way. That way you never have to guess

Answer (score 2):

Where possible, just use the latest versions to fix version issues.

Changing `1.4.2.RELEASE` to `2.0.1.RELEASE` works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Ideally you should remove the version completely, let Spring Boot take care of it.

Comment: Can i know what was the exact reason to change version? Thanks!

Comment: Not all versions are compatible with all versions of another library. For example, library1 is trying to call a method `helloWorld()` of library2 (version 1.0). Now if you upgrade library2 to version 2.0, this version may have the `helloWorld` method changed to `hiWorld()`. So you need to upgrade library1 as well, which would be calling the updated `hiWorld()` method.

Comment: Clearly explained Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use dependency versions provided by Spring Cloud project in my `dependencyManagement` section: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/

This way I don't have to manually put dependency versions and avoid problems like you just presented. Selecting dependency versions manually quickly becomes a huge pain and this approach uses versions that are tested by the community.

In case of Spring Cloud, Finchley release train works with Spring Boot 2.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Instead of individual version like as i have done in my pom.xml <version>Finchley.SR1</version> this statement will take care of child dependencies  right?

Comment: @thejasaitheja Exactly. Just like `spring-boot-starter-parent` takes care of core Spring dependencies (e.g. `spring-boot-starter-web`), `spring-cloud-dependencies` takes care of all your Spring Cloud dependencies, so you can just skip adding explicit versions in your POM.